# How to see the history of an array for a certain ip?

Tags: php, html, arrays

So I have an array that displays usernames at random to users who visit the site. So what I want to do is make it log the displayed usernames from the ip that has seen the usernames then display the logs on a different page like for example example.com/history but only the ip that has seen those usernames will see that history like each ip has different history. Here's what my code looks like:

```
<?php
$usrnames = file('https://www.example.com/usernames.txt');
$usernames = array_values(array_filter($usrnames, "trim"));
echo $usernames[array_rand($usernames)];
?>
```

Sorry if I did a bad job at explaining this, feel free to edit this.

Comment: Please clarify a little better. Thanks.

Comment: @BakriTotah You'll probably want to track history through a cookie (or PHP session), which is by the device's browser instead of IP. Doing this by IP is a pretty involved process.

Comment: So this would require writing the array of users names an IP has seen to a different table (I suggest storing that as a JSON object) and then querying that in order to display on the history table. If you get any amount of traffic though, that's going to turn in to a nightmare.

Comment: Cookies might be the better way to go, but it's not really clear what the actual objective is. And do you really want to be storing other user names in people's cookies? Then there's the multiple IP per user issue. How do you track that if you want to at all?

Comment: You should store this in a database. Also keep in mind an IP != an individual.

Comment: Unless you have a really good business case for it, I think it will be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 1):

#### By Session

You can something very similar with PHP Sessions. You can keep an array of the viewed usernames in a session array. This will track them by device browser, not by IP. Using PHP sessions will more accurately represent a "person" because it's unique to a device.

```
session_start();

$usrnames = file('https://www.example.com/usernames.txt');
$usernames = array_values(array_filter($usrnames, "trim"));
$chosen = $usernames[array_rand($usernames)];
echo $chosen; 

$_SESSION['history'][] = $chosen;
```

And then on the page where you want to show the viewed usernames:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['history']);
```

#### By Cookie

If you want to store the history indefinitely you'll need to use a cookie.

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['history'])) {
    $history = json_decode($_COOKIE['history'], true);
}

$usrnames = file('https://www.example.com/usernames.txt');
$usernames = array_values(array_filter($usrnames, "trim"));
$chosen = $usernames[array_rand($usernames)];
echo $chosen; 

$history[] = $chosen;

setcookie("history", json_encode($history), 2147483647, '/');
```

Then for the page where you want to show the history:

```
var_dump(json_decode($_COOKIE['history']), true);
```

Comment: @BakriTotah I've updated my answer with the cookie method. Sessions are dependent on your server architecture but the cookie method should work as long as the user doesn't clear their browser history.

Comment: @BakriTotah Sorry, was just missing a closing bracket. Use `(isset($_COOKIE['history']))`

Comment: @BakriTotah That's just from the `var_dump()` which is a debugging tool more than anything. You'll have to loop through the array with [Foreach](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

Comment: Yeah the extra text is just from the var_dump. Use a foreach loop and echo.